# howto sort an array with objects by property value length?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have the following array with objects:

```
var defaultSanitizer = [
    {"word": "large", "replaceWith":"L"},
    {"word": "os", "replaceWith":"One Size"},  
    {"word": "xlarge", "replaceWith":"XL"},
    {"word": "o/s", "replaceWith":"One Size"},
    {"word": "medium", "replaceWith":"M"}
    ...
];
```

(in reality this array is much larger)

I want to make a function so I can order the array by the length of a property value e.g. the property "word" of the objects.

Something like this:

```
function sortArrByPropLengthAscending(arr, property) {

    var sortedArr = [];

    //some code

    return sortedArr;

}
```

If I were to run the function sortArrByPropLengthAscending(defaultSanitizer, "word") it should return me a sorted array that looks like this:

```
sortedArr = [        
    {"word": "os", "replaceWith":"One Size"},  
    {"word": "o/s", "replaceWith":"One Size"},
    {"word": "large", "replaceWith":"L"},
    {"word": "xlarge", "replaceWith":"XL"},        
    {"word": "medium", "replaceWith":"M"}
    ...
]
```

How would you do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sortMultiDimensional(a,b)
{
    return ((a.word.length < b.word.length) ? -1 : ((a.word.length > b.word.length) ? 1 : 0));
}

var defaultSanitizer = [
    {"word": "large", "replaceWith":"L"},
    {"word": "os", "replaceWith":"One Size"},  
    {"word": "xlarge", "replaceWith":"XL"},
    {"word": "o/s", "replaceWith":"One Size"},
    {"word": "medium", "replaceWith":"M"}
];

defaultSanitizer.sort(sortMultiDimensional);
console.log(defaultSanitizer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array in place by the ascending length of property `propName` with:

```
function sortArray(array, propName) {
    array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[propName].length - b[propName].length;
    });
}
```

See the description of the [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.